# format date in a textbox before storing in access database

Tags: vb.net

I am entering the ate as 31122014 in a text box. on leaving the text box, it should show 31/12/2014 and the same should be store in mdb also.  Similarly for date like 01022014 (01-feb-2014) it should show as 01/02/2014 in vb.net.

Comment: Actual DateTime types do not have a format, they are simply a value.  If the Access column is a Date Type, just store a DateTime value to it.  The format is just how VS, VB and Access *display* the date to you

Comment: What code have you already tried?

Answer (score 1):

Date format for display purposes have nothing to do with how they should be stored in a database. If you need to store a date in a database, you use a DateTime column. The only time you need to format a date is to display it to the user. Date formatting should be done in the UI.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a long time since I've used Access, but after you've created the text box on your form, click on it, and check it's properties. You may need to create a custom input mask to do what your asking, but it is possible. Please google search MS Access > Input Mask